# Why my factory pattern return error while compiling?

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement simle factory pattern but when I try compile code i get error like:

**error: undefined reference to `vtable for Interface'**

**error: undefined reference to `typeinfo for Interface'**

```
class Interface{
public:
    virtual void set(const std::string &data);
    virtual void get(const std::string &data);
    virtual void show();
    virtual ~Interface(){}
};

class InterX : public Interface{
public:
    void set(const std::string &data){x++;}
    void get(const std::string &data){x--;}
    void show(){std::cout << x << std::endl;}
private:
    int x = 1;
};

class InterY : public Interface{
public:
    void set(const std::string &data){y++;}
    void get(const std::string &data){y--;}
    void show(){std::cout << y << std::endl;}
private:
    int y = 2;
};

class Factory{
public:
   static Interface* getInterface(const std::string interface_name){
       if(interface_name == "x") return new InterX();
       if(interface_name == "y") return new InterY();
       return nullptr;
   }
};

int main()
{
    Interface* interface = Factory::getInterface("x");
    return 0;
}
```

How could I fix that? When I commented line in main, the programs comiles

```
Interface* interface = Factory::getInterface("x");
```

Comment: `Interface::set` is declared but nowhere defined. Either make it pure virtual, or add a base implementation. Same goes for `get` and `show`.

Comment: Please, if you are asking a problem on C++ language specific issue, don't tag it as C, as it confounds many people not interested in non-C issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interface is not correct. You didn't implemented your function and they are not pure virtual. I think you meant them to be pure virtual:

```
class Interface{
public:
    virtual void set(const std::string &data) = 0;
    virtual void get(const std::string &data) = 0;
    virtual void show() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface(){}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to give implementations for your virtual functions like so:

```
virtual void set(const std::string &data){ (void)0; }; //Do nothing statements, (i think)
virtual void get(const std::string &data){ (void)0; };
virtual void show(){ (void)0; };
virtual ~Interface(){ (void)0; };
```

or declare them as pure virtuals:

```
virtual void set(const std::string &data) = 0;
virtual void get(const std::string &data) = 0;
virtual void show() = 0;
virtual ~Interface(){};
```